# Apply visa of a country from another county( not your home country)

Tags: solo-travel

How can I apply for visa to travel to spain when I am living in Tbilisi. But i am an indian passport holder?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to apply through the [Spanish Embassy in Tbilisi](https://www.embassypages.com/missions/embassy21568/), just as you would if you were in India. They might want to know why you're not applying in India. Be ready with a credible explanation.